# How to make a Thread wait until an Array contains elements

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have two Threads Robot which both have an `AssemblyLine` lineIn and lineOut. The `AssemblyLines` are `Arrays` which contain elements. The lineOut from Robot 1 is the lineIn from Robot2, so they are "connected" via that `AssemblyLine`.

The Robots is picking up an element from the AssemblyLine lineIn, waiting a give amount of time and then putting the element down on the AssemblyLine lineOut.

How can I let the second robot wait or interrupt until the first robot put down the first element on the array?

That's my solution, the problem is I heard `Thread.sleep() + while()` generates massive overhead:

```
public void run() {
    PrintedBoard printedBoard = null;
    while (lineIn.size() == 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
    }

    while (printedBoard != PrintedBoard.STOPPER) {
        printedBoard = lineIn.pickUp();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        lineOut.putDown(printedBoard);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Give** the second robot a **reference** to something where he can **access the array property**, for example a reference to the first robot. After that, in his `run` method (main logic) check the array length and then call some **sleep** method (there are multiply ways to yield CPU time). Pack this into some kind of `while` loop.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: Java has library data structures for this, any reason you're not using them?  Time to look at the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: @Zabuza 'check the array length and then call some sleep method' NO!

Comment: Use a blocking queue.  using sleep for this is lame.

Comment: @MartinJames Why not? Would work. Note that with *length* I didn't meant `array.length` (arrays are always of fixed length thus there is no *empty* in this sense). Could have been a bit confusing I must admit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

I'll give a minimal example that should showcase how it **can** be done.

The second robot needs some **reference** to where it can access the **array** or the property you want to check, for example a reference to the first robot. After that you create some `while` loop which **checks the condition** and **yields CPU time**, for example by **sleeping**.

Since arrays are always of **fixed length** you will need some additional logic that determines when a *true* value was entered into the array. Or you determine a special value that represents *no value* (like `null`). Alternatively you could use data-structures like `List` or `Queue` in the first place which already provide `isEmpty` methods.

```
public class FirstRobot() extends Thread {
    // Place for 10 objects
    private Object[] data = new Object[10];

    public boolean isDataEmpty() {
        // Check all entries for "null"
        for (Object entry : data) {
            if (entry != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Other thread stuff
}

public class SecondRobot extends Thread {
    private FirstRobot firstRobot;

    public SecondRobot(FirstRobot firstRobot) {
        // Second robot needs to access the "length" of the data
        this.firstRobot = firstRobot
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Wait for data to not be empty
        while (firstRobot.isDataEmpty()) {
            // Wait and try again afterwards
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        // Data is now not "empty"
    }
}
```

---

### Notes

However as you might have noted the current implementation of `isDataEmpty` is **slow** as it checks every entry each time. You could easily improve on that by setting some `boolean` (a flag) to `true` once you add your first data value.

However a more appropriate data-structure would probably be a `Queue`. It can check `isEmpty` very fast and with `poll` you can get and remove the head element. And in your special case where multiple threads need to access the data-structure you probably want a **thread-safe** data-structure.

And note that there already is a data-structure called `BlockingQueue` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)) which, when trying to get an element, waits (blocks) until there is an element to fetch. It could be possible that this is exactly what you want.

Also note that you can approach this type of problem with several different approaches. I only showed one, you might research a bit for the individual parts of the solution and take a look at the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AssemblyLine{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(n); //provide queue size n

        RobotLineIn robotIn = new RobotLineIn(queue);
        RobotLineOut robotOut = new RobotLineOut(queue);

        new Thread(robotIn).start();
        new Thread(robotOut).start();
    }
}

public class RobotLineIn implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue queue = null;

    public RobotLineIn(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
          //read your data here from assembly line and put in queue.
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

public class RobotLineOut implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue queue = null;

    public RobotLineOut(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
          //read data from queue.
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of just dumping code, you should consider explaining it, and why it's better than what OP is trying.

Comment: I like the approach using `BlockingQueue` but I'm with @eis, OP probably benefits more from this answer if you explain it step by step.